# Check if value exists in multiple sheets

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have one excel with the following sheets

```
MAY
JUNE
JULY
AUGUST
```

Inside each sheet i have one column (A) with around 200 rows and in each cell I have a 6 digit number.

I would like to somehow in column (B) next to each number to check all sheets and if the number exists to return any text value for example "OK".

So if I write the number "000000" in Sheet JULY, Column A, line 67 and this number exists in Sheet MAY, Column A, line 120, I would like to see the word "OK" in Sheet JULY, Column B, line 67

What I have tried so far is:

```
=IFERROR(IF(MATCH(A2,MAY!$A:$A,0),"YES",),"NO")
```

But this one only checks one Sheet (MAY) I would like to have the option to check two or more Sheets.

Thanks

Comment: A simple `Sum` of `Countif`s will do the job. Have you considered it? If it could be more entries of the same code on one column use instead a `Sum` of `Match`es.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there. The formula you want is:

```
=IF(SUM(If(IFERROR(MATCH(A2,MAY!$A:$A,0),0)=0,0,1),If(IFERROR(MATCH(A2,JUNE!$A:$A,0),0)=0,0,1),…)<4,"No","Yes")
```

Please complete the formula with the others sheets you need or adjust it to your case.

Note that `MATCH` function will return a non null value is it finds a match. The Error catch `IFERROR` returns `0`. So, if the any of the `MATCH`s fails, the `SUM` returns a number less than `4`.

Comment: Construct your formula from inside out. Start with just one `Sheet`. Try to understand it and you will find the error!